# How to open uiimage in ImageViewer via code?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, image-viewer

I have added some images in my iOS app. Now i want to open that images in iPhone/iPad image viewer when i click on them. Is it possible using code? and how?

Comment: Tell me that how are you able to tap (as there is no pointer or mouse to click) any image without showing them on screen?

Comment: @Wolvorin- i already said that i have showed the images on screen, and i am also able to tap on them.